# Google Apps Script personalised Email notifications

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want a script that will send out an email from a spreadsheet when a new row of data is entered. I'd like some of this data to be included in the subject, and some more data and a link to the spreadsheet in the main body.

I'm currently using a script that sends an email when a certain column in the spreadsheet is updated, but I'd now like to personalise it a bit more and make it quicker for the recipient to review without having to always open the spreadsheet.

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eq8Kpn0oOBItaGaKaOOLa1qLZZ2_l2gg6wOkLa6GMWo/edit#gid=872382993) is my spreadsheet:

And this is my current script:

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Requests");
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();

  if (cell.indexOf('F')!=-1)
  {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "email@yourdomain.co.uk",
      subject: "Request",
      htmlBody: "There has been a new request. <br \> <br \> To review it, use the link below. <br \> <br \> " +
           "<a href=\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eq8Kpn0oOBItaGaKaOOLa1qLZZ2_l2gg6wOkLa6GMWo/edit#gid=872382993\">Requests</a>"
    });
  }
}
```

I'd like the **quantity (column F)** and **date (column E)** to be included in the email subject, and the **quantity (F)**, **date (E)** and **depot (D)** included in the main body, with the link to the spreadsheet.

EDIT: Columns G, H & I would be filled in at a later date by the recipient of the email.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

My script is now looking like this:

```
function getActiveRowValues(sheet){
  var cellRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  // get depot value
  var depotCell = sheet.getRange("D" + cellRow);
  var depot = depotCell.getDisplayValue();
  // get date value
  var dateCell = sheet.getRange("E" + cellRow);
  var date = dateCell.getDisplayValue();
  // get quantity value
  var quantCell = sheet.getRange("F" + cellRow);
  var quant = quantCell.getDisplayValue();
  // return an object with your values
  return {
    depot: depot,
    date: date,
    quantity: quant
  } 

if (cell.indexOf('F')!=-1)
{
  var rowVals = getActiveRowValues(sheet);
  MailApp.sendEmail({
   to: "email@yourdomain.co.uk",
   subject: "Request" + " date " + rowVals.date + " quant " + rowVals.quant,
   htmlBody: "There has been a new request. <br \> <br \> To review it, use the link below. <br \> <br \> " + "<table border = \"1\" cellpadding=\"10\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr><th>Depot</th><th>Date</th><th>Quantity</th></tr><tr><td>"+rowVals.depot+"</td><td>"+rowVals.date+"</td><td>"+rowVals.quant+"</td></tr></table>" + 
       "<a href=\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eq8Kpn0oOBItaGaKaOOLa1qLZZ2_l2gg6wOkLa6GMWo/edit#gid=872382993\">Requests</a>"
  });
}}
```

But getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveRange" of undefined. (line 2,
>   file "Code")

Comment: I'm sorry, what's the question?

Comment: I'd like the date and quantity to be included in the email subject, and in the email body the date, quantity and depot, alongside a link to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this function in your script that will extract your required details from the respective column:

```
/**
* get values of depot, date and quantity from their respective cells.
* @returns    {Object.<string, string>}
*/
function getActiveRowValues(sheet){
  var cellRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  // get depot value
  var depotCell = sheet.getRange("D" + cellRow);
  var depot = depotCell.getDisplayValue();
  // get date value
  var dateCell = sheet.getRange("E" + cellRow);
  var date = dateCell.getDisplayValue();
  // get quantity value
  var quantCell = sheet.getRange("F" + cellRow);
  var quant = quantCell.getDisplayValue();
  // return an object with your values
  return {
    depot: depot,
    date: date,
    quantity: quant
  } 
}
```

Then call `getActiveRowValues` inside your **if** condition and also update your subject and htmlBody variables:

```
if (cell.indexOf('F')!=-1)
{
  var rowVals = getActiveRowValues(sheet);
  MailApp.sendEmail({
   to: "email@yourdomain.co.uk",
   subject: "Request" + " date " + rowVals.date + " quant " + rowVals.quantity,
   htmlBody: "There has been a new request. <br \> <br \> To review it, use the link below. <br \> <br \> " + "<table border = \"1\" cellpadding=\"10\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr><th>Depot</th><th>Date</th><th>Quantity</th></tr><tr><td>"+rowVals.depot+"</td><td>"+rowVals.date+"</td><td>"+rowVals.quantity+"</td></tr></table>" + 
       "<a href=\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eq8Kpn0oOBItaGaKaOOLa1qLZZ2_l2gg6wOkLa6GMWo/edit#gid=872382993\">Requests</a>"
  });
}
```

And your overall script should look like this:

```
function sendNotification(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Requests");
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var emailAdd = "email@yourdomain.co.uk";
  if(event.range.getA1Notation().indexOf("F") > -1 && sheet.getRange("F" + row).getDisplayValue() && emailAdd.length > 1)
  {
     var rowVals = getActiveRowValues(sheet);
     MailApp.sendEmail({
       to: emailAdd,
       subject: "Request" + " date " + rowVals.date + " quant " + rowVals.quantity,
       htmlBody: "There has been a new request. <br \> <br \> To review it, use the link below. <br \> <br \> " + "<table border = \"1\" cellpadding=\"10\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr><th>Depot</th><th>Date</th><th>Quantity</th></tr><tr><td>"+rowVals.depot+"</td><td>"+rowVals.date+"</td><td>"+rowVals.quantity+"</td></tr></table>" + 
       "<a href=\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eq8Kpn0oOBItaGaKaOOLa1qLZZ2_l2gg6wOkLa6GMWo/edit#gid=872382993\">Requests</a>"
      });
  }
}

/**
* get values of depot, date and quantity from their respective cells.
* @returns    {Object.<string, string>}
*/
function getActiveRowValues(sheet){
  var cellRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  // get depot value
  var depotCell = sheet.getRange("D" + cellRow);
  var depot = depotCell.getDisplayValue();
  // get date value
  var dateCell = sheet.getRange("E" + cellRow);
  var date = dateCell.getDisplayValue();
  // get quantity value
  var quantCell = sheet.getRange("F" + cellRow);
  var quant = quantCell.getDisplayValue();
  // return an object with your values
  return {
    depot: depot,
    date: date,
    quantity: quant
  } 
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to send me an email, though to me it looks like what I'm after. As a complete newbie I'm not sure I've input it correctly - as in I'm not sure what you mean by "inside your condition."

Comment: From the code above that you have wirtten; this is your condition to send an email: if (cell.indexOf('F')!=-1){ //send email }. this will trigger when cell.indexOf('F') != -1 will be true means your active cell should be in column F only then this condition will trigger. For me this condition makes no sense but I am not aware of the whole scenario. Though if your above code works fine then I think this should work fine too by replacing the block of code inside if (cell.indexOf('F')!=-1){ } with the one that I have written above

Comment: The cell.indexOf('F')!=-1 I got from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374737/google-sheets-script-that-sends-a-notification-upon-form-submission-if-data-is-r I just amended the script to work for me, and it's largely the one I included in my original post.

Comment: I'm getting an error with this part I believe:  var cellRow = ss.getActiveRange().getRow();

Comment: Sorry my bad! I made a mistake in this line: var cellRow = ss.getActiveRange().getRow(); ss should be sheet. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for editing your script. Unfortunately I'm still getting the error "TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveRange" of undefined. (line 2, file "Code")" appear when I try to run it.

Comment: I have updated my original post to include the script I am now trying.

Comment: Oh no you did it wrong! You should not remove sendNotification() function from the script. My answer was pointing out to update the code in the if condition. Now again check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I've copied it straight over (amending the email address), but I'm still not receiving any emails! I've got the sendNotification function trigger set up, but how am I meant to trigger the getActiveRowValues function as well? When I run them separately, I'm still getting the same error message as before. I am a complete novice, so highly likely I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: try looking into my script: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i8d41MpjBFB8Ug9FYBzWj6YZiBnrBc8z-QBvS6cIDGY/edit?usp=sharing 
Change your email address in the script and then enter the details in the respective columns of the spread sheet and see if you get the email.

Comment: Though I've now got a problem in that I get another email when columns G,H or I have data added. These columns would have data added at a later date as part of a review, and I wouldn't want an email sent when they are used. Is there part of the script I can amend or remove to sort this?

Comment: Use the event param from sendNotification event handler. `sendNotification(event)` and then add the condition in your if statement: `event.range.getA1Notation().indexOf("F") > -1`
Check I have updated the code above as well as in the sheet I shared above.

Comment: Unfortunately that created an error: TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined.

Comment: Cancel that. It does actually run when triggered through the spreadsheet. I don't understand why it shows and error in the editor but as it works in the sheet I don't really care!! Thanks a lot again.

Comment: My Pleasure! And yes the error is because `event` variable is passed when the `onEdit` event triggers. If you will execute the function directly from the script then the `event` variable is `undefined`. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate values on the HTML of the body and the subject

```
function sendNotification() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Requests");
var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();

var thisIsAVariable = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Requests").getRange("A1").getValue();

if (cell.indexOf('F')!=-1)
{
MailApp.sendEmail({
 to: "email@yourdomain.co.uk",
 subject: "Request" + + thisIsAVariable +,
 htmlBody: "concatenate like: "+ thisIsAVariable +"There has been a new request. <br \> <br \> To review it, use the link below. <br \> <br \> " + thisIsAVariable +
           "<a href=\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eq8Kpn0oOBItaGaKaOOLa1qLZZ2_l2gg6wOkLa6GMWo/edit#gid=872382993\">Requests</a>"
});
}}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to do anything different to what I already have.